# Canonical “Plz send codez” answer?

Tags: discussion, canonical, help-vampire

We have many answers about what to do about no-effort “Plz send codez” questions, but invariably we get enablers [justifying doing these peoples' work for them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49284515/22437) with remarks like “we were all beginners once” or “I'm just trying to help”.

Scattered in the discussions are reasons why answering these types of questions harms, not helps, the site, but I could find no one simple guideline or explanation about why that is and why one shouldn't answer such questions. Is there a canonical guideline or answer I could point to that explains the problems with answering these kinds of questions?

Comment: [Relevant answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077), in otherwise (not entirely) unrelated [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758). At least *some* of the answers in there come from disappointed users who *just* want "ur useful codez", thanks-in-advance included.

Comment: "Plz send codez" is not directly an issue.  The issue is a vast majority of the time, the problem is that (1) the question is a duplicate or is so broad that it has multiple duplicates, and/or (2) the question is very broad that pages of code and explanation could be written, and/or (3) the question is unclear as to what the actual problem is, and/or (4) the question isn't actually a question, it is just "I want to make a chat app, what should I do".

Comment: This idea that you're gonna motivate folks to not answer by telling them it's "bad for the site" is... wrong-headed. It's like telling people to recycle for the sake of sea turtles; it appeals to a small subset of people who mostly weren't doing it anyway. If the Q&A is never useful to anyone else, then the author is making poor use of their time and most will eventually burn out - so encourage people to write reusable answers *for their own sake.*

Comment: @psubsee2003: all four of your categories get answered. It's part of the problem, not part of the solution.

Comment: @usr2564301 wasn't saying it wasn't a problem.  But point was the asking for code isn't the issue.  It is the type of questions that usually get asked that are the problem

Comment: @Shog9 We tell question authors that their bad questions are bad for the site.  It doesn't always have the desirable effect (because many of them just don't care), but that doesn't mean that we don't try, or discourage people from attempting to convince people asking bad questions to try to improve.  We also don't just say that people asking bad questions will just burn out and stop after a while, and recognize that we *do* need to attempt to deal with the problem in *some* way (even if it's not a war we can ever win completely).  Why is it any different for answerers?

Comment: No one's arguing here that bad answers are bad for the site, @Servy. The argument is that *any* answers to bad questions are bad for the site. Even useful answers. Maybe especially useful answers. This is based on an old theory that a significant number of questions are generated by either the same small group of people (unlikely) or by people who learn to ask exclusively by reading existing obscure questions that help no one and mimic their style (implausible). The truth is, these questions are no different than the millions that plagued past generations going all the way back to USENET.

Comment: When I joined Stack Overflow, I was phasing out my activity on another site that suffered from this same problem. Worse than the problem itself were roving gangs of vigilantes who spent their time getting into long, stupid arguments on every lousy question - all the while wearing the fig-leaf of "doing it for the good of the site". Stack Overflow offered alternatives: downvoting, editing, closing. Less noise, more results. So why return to the same noisy techniques that *didn't save any previous community?* Because it *feels* like you're doing something. But it's as counterproductive as always

Comment: @Shog9 We *define* bad questions as questions that either can't, or are *extremely* unlikely to, attract useful answers.  Therefore, saying that answers to a bad question are almost certainly bad is true *by definition*.  If the question is attracting useful answers, either it is a very rare exception, or the question isn't actually a bad question.  One issue here is that so many people equate a useful answer with a correct answer.  Just because an answer is *correct* doesn't mean that it's useful.

Comment: There are two reasons a question can be bad, either it *can't* be answered (i.e. unclear), or answers posted to it wouldn't be useful (i.e. off topic).  In the first case an answer can't be useful because, by definition, the question is unanswerable. For the latter case, the answers to those types of questions aren't useful, which is why those types of questions aren't allowed.  So the point here is not that "useful answers aren't useful", but rather the statement that people sharing their opinions, or positing correct answers to off topic questions, etc., *isn't useful*.

Comment: @Shog9 To your last point, that something I can most certainly agree with.  People going around just telling people not to post answers to X types of questions, and getting into lengthy comment arguments about it, is not a particularly effective way of actually solving this problem.  By all means, we should try to figure out better ways of dealing with the problem that are less noisy. I just have a problem saying that people shouldn't care about answers that aren't useful being posted; talking about more effective ways for people to address answers that aren't useful besides comments is great.

Comment: That's a lazy way to define a bad answer, @Servy. It absolves anyone from having to actually read the answer, know anything about the topic, or make a specific argument for why there's a problem with the post - all you need do is pick out some problem with the question and you've gained license to damn every answer posted without so much as a cursory scan. And that's crap. If bad questions are those that attract bad answers, then a question which attracts a good answer cannot be a bad question - so by your definition, *only* a strong argument for why an answer is useless can damn a question.

Comment: @Shog9 If someone posts the question "what color should I paint my bikeshed" then you *don't* need to read the answers to know whether or not they're going to be a useful post (on SO).  Not that I'm advocating voting on answers without reading them (because sometimes reading the answer allows you to realize that you really did miss something in the question, and that the question *wasn't* a bad question).  But you *would* have a specific argument for why there's a problem with the post.  It would be that it's off topic (in my example), or that it's sharing one person's opinion, etc.

Comment: Like I've said, if you see an answer that you think is a good answer, then odds are the question *isn't* a bad question.  There are rare exceptions, but it's generally true.  Of course it's also possible that information that could otherwise be useful *ceases to be useful* because of problems with a question. For example, if you post a useful answer *to the wrong question* (say, because the answerer misunderstood it) then the answer isn't useful, even if it could have been useful if posted to a different question.

Comment: @Shog9 And no, we *don't* need to see bad answers on a question in order to conclude that a question cannot attract good answers.  Back to my earlier example, if someone asks what color they should paint their bikeshed we can say that that type of question isn't able to produce useful answers *even if answers haven't been posted yet*, because questions with the problems that it had (being off topic, being an opinion poll, etc.) have historically proven to not produce useful answers.

Comment: Bikeshed questions aren't what we're discussing here though.

Comment: @Shog9 Indeed, I intentionally took an example of a question that would be unambiguously be considered bad, so that things wouldn't devolve into a question of whether or not the question was actually appropriate for the site.  The same reasoning would apply to a question that is missing way too much information to be answerable, or asking for something that would take a book to answer it, or whatever other problems the post might have that make it inappropriate for the site.

Comment: Those are all different problems, @Servy. It's the Anna Karenina Principle: all good questions are alike, but each poorly-asked question is poorly-asked in its own way. A question may suffer from any number of problems; some of those affect answers, others dictate answers, others have little effect on answers at all... A good question must avoid all of the problems, but saying a question isn't good doesn't tell you much beyond that it has fallen victim to one of a vast array of pitfalls; what effect it has on the answers will depend on its specifics.

Comment: @Shog9 and not only is answering such questions likely to help only the question asker, it's likely that only the question asker is ever likely to upvote said answer. One should answer in such a way to make others upvote it as useful to *them*.

Comment: @Shog9 What would make a question a bad question that is still likely to generate quality answers that would be useful to people?  If the question would be likely to generate quality answers useful to other people then I'd assert *it's not actually a bad question*.  If a given question fell into some particular pitfall *that didn't impact the quality of the answers it can get* then why is that even a pitfall at all?  In my experience there just *aren't* questions whose quality has no impact on their answers.  What are problems a question can have that don't impact the quality of their answers?

Comment: A question can be well-written, attract useful answers, and completely off-topic - that's why we first ended up with Server Fault & Super User (and, heck, Meta) @Servy. A question can be well-written, attract useful answers, and be an exact duplicate of a previous question, thus dividing up the information in multiple places. A question can attract useful answers, but be so broad as to make finding the answer to a specific problem difficult if not impossible - dozens of old "tips and tricks" questions suffered from this problem. There are scores of past discussions on all of these problems.

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, and all of those problems with the question *prevent those answers from being useful*.  You've defined those answers as being useful, but then stated that the problems with those questions have *prevented them from actually helping people* (aka being useful).  As a result, those answers *aren't* useful, and they aren't useful *because of the problems with those questions*.  Information that would be useful *if found by the people that need to see it*, but that *isn't* actually able to be found by the people who need to see it *isn't a helpful answer*.

Comment: So the *reason* we consider those types of questions bad questions is that *regardless* of what answers are posted to them, they won't actually be useful *because the problems with the question prevent the content from being found*.  It is for that reason that questions with those problems *can't have a useful answer*, regardless of how correct the content is or how useful it *would be* if it could actually be found.

Comment: That's some really convoluted logic, @Servy. Google finds SU questions on SO as easily as it finds them on SU; the problems caused by hosting those questions here aren't related to their answers not being useful but rather the likelihood of them being answered well *at all*. Same with duplicates: we explicitly *don't delete them* because they can and do help folks find their way to useful answers - the catch is that those answers have to be consolidated. I could go on, but I'm out of space in this comment and none of this is new - so please refer back to my Anna Karenina comment above.

Comment: @Shog9 You gave examples of questions that *you* felt resulted in the answers not actually being discoverable.  If you're now arguing that the content *can* be found, then apparently *there isn't actually a problem*.  If the questions are resulting in quality answers that are discoverable by the people that need to find them, then I'd assert that *the question is not in fact a bad question*, as it has succeeded in its goal of producing a quality, discoverable answer.  It's for that reason that *some* duplicates *can* be good questions (even though most are not, as they don't do that).

Comment: We're going in circles, @Servy. My assertion is that there are numerous problems. MANY problems. A veritable *cornucopia* of problems... that can and do afflict questions. The nature of those problems, their effects and how they can be addressed vary wildly. Yes, this would all be a lot *simpler* if we could pretend that all problems are essentially the same with the same effects and can be dealt with in the same way... That's The Programmer Way: when complexity rears its head, add another level of abstraction. But it doesn't work here.

Comment: @Shog9 Of course there are lots of different types of problems that a question can have, and of course all of the problems a question has can't be solved in the same way, I never contradicted either of those statements.  All I've said is that if a question has problems *they virtually always impact the quality of its answers*, because if they didn't then *they wouldn't actually be problems*, because they aren't preventing quality discoverable answers.  There are lots of ways a question can prevent itself from having useful answers, and they're solved differently.

Comment: And, that's still not an accurate statement @Servy. Questions that motivate poor-quality answers *are A problem* - they are not the ONLY problem. Even if that is the only problem under discussion, the proof of *that specific problem's existence* is the presence of poor-quality answers: answers that are not useful to readers with the relevant problem. That specific test *does not work* for every problem; a question about cheese-making that gets useful cheese-making answers is still off-topic here; a question with a vague title that gets a useful answer still has a vague title.

Comment: @Shog9 A question having a vague title, assuming the vagueness is severe enough to prevent readers with the problem from finding it, *does impact the quality of the answers*, because it prevents them from actually being found.  The ability of an answer to actually be found *is a part of that answer's usefulness*.   You're just asserting that an answer is useful, and then describing qualities of it that prevent it from being useful. If the title isn't vague enough to prevent people from finding the answer, then it's a question with a problem not severe enough to make it a bad question.

Comment: This isn't Quora, @Servy. There's more to questions than just a title. Generally a LOT more. A vague title is ***a** problem* but not the same problem as a vague question, or a broad question, or an off-topic question. Systems that predated SO were clogged with questions titled "C++ Doubt" - that was a BIG PROBLEM in those systems, because *those titles never changed*; I'd see absolutely fantastic answers posted and then never be able to find them again. We have tools to fix that on SO. Heck, answerers can fix that. Lot less work to fix a title than to burn down every thread that has a bad one

Comment: @Shog9 So in that case the problem was severe enough that it has prevented those answers form actually being useful to you.  That answer didn't help you strictly because of a problem with the question, and having nothing to do with the answer.  If the question would have been fixed, that answer would actually have been useful to you.  You've just demonstrated that a problem with the question has prevented that answer from being useful.

Comment: Enough with the convoluted logic, @Servy: if the answer is useful when the question is found, then the answer is useful. If the question cannot be found, that's not a problem with the answer. The solution to the problem of a bad title is to *fix the damn title* - not harass the answerer because they answered a question with a bad title. If you want to say something useful to the answerer, suggest that they too could edit the title. "Let's make a canonical question and badger answerers to not answer questions with bad titles" is not a solution to bad titles.

Comment: @Shog9 How is it convoluted logic to say that an answer that couldn't help you solve a problem isn't useful?  I'd say it's convoluted to say that an answer is useful when it was utterly incapable of helping you solve your problem.  Now of course the proper course of action to take in that instance is to edit the title.  It's always preferable to just *fix* a problem and make it go away instead of indicating that a problem exists without fixing it, *when that's possible*.  In your example, it is possible, so that's the best course of action.  Not all problems can be fixed like that.

Comment: Which is why you don't try to cram *all problems* into the same mould, @Servy. You asked at the start why, if we tell the author of a bad question that their question is bad, we shouldn't do the same for the answerer of a bad question. The answer is "because doing so is useless". Telling an answerer "hey, more people could find your answer if you edited the title" is specific, actionable guidance; "hey, you answered a bad question" isn't.

Comment: @Shog9 And, as I said before, I'm *completely* on the same page with you in that respect.  Your first example comment is not a useful comment.  The answer isn't useful, but the comment has not helped anyone actually solve the problem, the comment is just noise.  The second comment, as you have said, is providing actionable guidance on how the answerer can make their answer more useful.  Of course, we don't comment on questions to literally say, "this is a bad question" either, we explain why and provide actionable guidance on how to improve it or we don't comment at all.

Comment: Did you happen to look at the thread that prompted this discussion, @Servy?

Comment: @Shog9 I looked at it a bit, neither the question nor the answer were particularly remarkable.  I've looked it over somewhat more closely now.  I think it's pretty clear to say that the comment chain on the answer wasn't *productive*. It was civil (of what I can see, I don't know if there are deleted comments), but I don't expect the answer to have any interest in changing their behavior as a result, so while I agree with the commenters that the answer wasn't useful, I don't expect that them saying as much in a comment actually helped accomplish anything.

Comment: Right. If you can't explain the problem in a way that connects with the author, you're wasting your time - or expecting them to care about sea turtles. @Servy

Comment: @Shog9 So I'm on board with your statement that comments like those aren't productive, but I *do* agree that the problems those commenters pointed out are real, so I just want to make sure that we're framing the discussion from the point of view of, "how can we convey this information (or better still, produce the desired result) in a productive manner" rather than just talking about how we can get people to stop caring about those problems and ignore them when they see them.

Comment: The first step there is to *define the problem*, @Servy. The first comment on that answer was "tell the author to read /help/how-to-ask"; presumably the author thought that /help/how-to-ask contains something about not asking for code in it, which it doesn't. Then the author of *this* question posts a comment linking to the Help Vampire meta question, presumably thinking that *it* contains something about not asking for code in it... Which it also doesn't. So we got all these people running around misidentifying problems, is it any wonder they're offering crap advice?